# Events that arent triggered by their buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I generated two buttons and put them into a list of buttons..

```
       List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
       Button pgs=new Button
            for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
                        pgs.Width = 20;
                        pgs.Command += obtainTopicsPerPage_Click;
                        pgs.CommandName = i.ToString();
                        pgs.Text =i.ToString();

                        btns.Add(tPage.ToString());
                        buttons.Add(pgs);
```

I added the buttons to a placeholder, and they appear on the page.

The event that they have is the following:

```
   void obtainTopicsPerPage_Click(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in tPages)
        {
            if (item.Key == e.CommandName)
            {
                foreach (var posts in item.Value)
                {
                    posts.ExecuteAll();
                }
            }
        }
         MyButtonTable();
    }
```

It doesn't matter what the functions do (they simply create tables and make it look like posts in a forum page)..

Now when the user clicks any one of the buttons that appear on the screen..none of the events are being triggered.. I put a breaking point inside the eventhanlder method and the web application doesn't reach there.

All I am concerned is why the buttons aren't attached to the event handling method that I gave them..why when I set the break point in the event it never triggers.

What should happen, when a button is clicked.. the event should should be triggered first, and the page should load second. But that doesn't happen..what happens is the button event being skipped, and the page load event is triggered with every postback after the button click..

Updated:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string[] d;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         d = new string[] { "dfadfas", "daads", "dasda", "dads" };
        Buttons();
    }
    List<Button> btns;
    public void Buttons()
    {
        btns = new List<Button>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            Button d = new Button();
            d.Text = "Click me";
            d.Click += Me_Click;
            btns.Add(d);

        }
       function();

    }
    public void function()
    {
        foreach (var item in btns)
        {
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(item);
        }

    }
    public int i { get{object o=ViewState["i"];return (o==null)?0:(int)o;} set{ViewState["i"]=value;} }
    public void Me_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (var item in d)
        {
            Label da= new Label();
            da.Text = "d"+i+++"<br/>";
            this.Controls.Add(da);

        }


    }
}
```

The working code above..

I tested by saving the buttons list with Session. Here I recreate the buttons at PreInit

```
 void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Button> btn = (List<Button>)Session["Buttons"];//debugging shows 2 buttons
    if (btn != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in btn)
        {
            item.Width = 20;
            item.Command += obtainTopicsPerPage_Click;
            item.CommandName = tPage.ToString();
            item.Text = tPage.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your first block of code does not appear to be valid - please check it and correct.

Comment: It works. i posted some of it... all buttons are valid.and the list

Comment: Your code may be valid in your project but look at it - what you posted here isn't valid.  For starters, your for loop has no braces.

Comment: You mentioned that when you use Click you lose some of your data. This makes me wonder if you have two problems. First, getting in a muddle with regards to page events and the sequence in which they occur, and second getting your custom event to work. Our 'Evil Greebo' friend is right, a bit more code would help us.

Comment: As an aside - Please stop using variable names like "d".  You've defined d in two places - once at the page level and once in your button creation - the code becomes quite hard to follow when you do that.  Let your variable names be informative - telling us what they are intended to do with their names.

Comment: That was a sample , which shows when u design buttons programmatically, you dont need to use prepage_init,,cause the buttons event fires before page_load event..so it is irrelevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me, and should hopefully give you an idea.  I know it's very simplistic but follows on from what you've provided. When you click the buttons the page Reloads therefore recreating the buttons and setting everything up again. To avoid that happening check that Page.IsPostBack is false.

```
public partial class GuessNumber : System.Web.UI.Page {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        lblResult.Text += "Written in by Page_Load <br />";
    }


    protected void LoveMyButtons_click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        string response = txtGuess.Text;

        lblResult.Text += string.Format("LoveMybuttons " + response + " <br />");
    }

    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        CreateButtons();
    }


    List<Button> btns;
    public void CreateButtons() {

        btns = new List<Button>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            Button butt = new Button();
            butt.Text = "Click me";
            butt.Click += LoveMyButtons_click;
            btns.Add(butt);

        }
        AddMyButtonsToAPlaceHolder();
    }

    public void AddMyButtonsToAPlaceHolder() {
        foreach (var item in btns) {
            plhButtonStore.Controls.Add(item);
        }

    }

}




<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtGuess" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnPeanut" runat="server" Text="Guess" />

    <br /><br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblNumberOfGuesses" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhButtonStore" runat="server" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: I get what the mistake was. The button fires the page_Load event before its eventhandler.. Click or command or whatever it be..am i right?

Comment: What happens is Page_PreInit runs first, but as it calls CreateButtons this gets ran every time you refresh the page, which clicking a Button does as well.

Comment: The button cannot fire its own event handler. The event handler responds to an event, either someone clicking on the button, or something mimicking this, for example jQuery or some javascript function.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you are using the right event? Shouldn't you be using [Button.Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click.aspx) ?

Comment: Command should work, but he did not add the handler correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This  `pgs.Command += obtainTopicsPerPage_Click;` should be `pgs.Command += new CommandEventHandler(obtainTopicsPerPage_Click);`

You did not add the Command Handler correctly  `new CommandEventHandler(obtainTopicsPerPage_Click);`

**Edit:** Since you are adding dynamic controls, On the page load your code should executed again to fire the event.

Comment: No, command should work as long as it goes to a command event handler.

Comment: But if i use click, i lose all the info that is associated with the buttons..their text/numeric value for example

Comment: In .NET 4.0 the synax Object.Event += HandlerEvent(); is valid, the redundant "new Handler(instance);" format is no longer required.

Comment: I have just updated my answer. try to get latest answer and check, it will work 100%.

Comment: Are you adding these buttons at page load ?

Comment: i set a breakpoint..it wont go inside..it wont attach the controls..:(

Comment: I tried a way to attach buttons with events on a blank webform,, i know it works..but on the code in my webform it doesnt work :(

Comment: I followed with debugging on that pgs.Click line..the code does reach it..but no controls are attached :(

Comment: Dynamic controls should be recreated on page post back, you need to make sure your dynamic controls creation block executed on server side on page postback.

Comment: I have just tested at my end and it works fine to me. there must be some other problem I guess.

Comment: Button b = new Button();
        b.Click += obtainTopicsPerPage_Click; even if i do this.... just one button on the web form..it doesnt work..

Comment: please email me that webpage at toakhtar@hotmail.com

Comment: copy and paste the update i posted above...it works too..but my code doesnt work....

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with using Command.

Try this on a new page as a starting point and you should see the Button1_Command event throw the expected exception.  I certainly do  :)

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button pgs = new Button();
        pgs.Command += Button1_Command;
        Controls.Add(pgs);
    }

    void Button1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

I suspect a problem elsewhere in your code we're not seeing.  Show us more of the code related to holding the buttons, etc., please.

And by the way, YES, it does compile and RUN (though I forgot the form1 reference ;) )
[image: Good grief...]

Comment: It will not compile even !!. I have just tested.

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you using?  It compiles and runs perfectly for me in VS2010/.NET 4

Comment: it does compile,, i tested it.....But why my code doesnt work.. it wont trigger the event ..whyh

Comment: I'm not sure - I've tried your code on my end and it is working - the behavior is funky but the events are firing.

Comment: Try stopping your local web server and cleaning your solution files (Build -> Clean Solution)  - I wonder if there's some caching issues going on under the hood...

Comment: I think some people are right.. .. i used one button in the load event...and attached the event to it..it fired.. But those buttons in the list..they dont fire..I guess it is a matter of where i put the buttons. The page load event does seem to fire before the button event...it is very weird...

Comment: If they're right then your code shouldn't execute the event on my machine, but it did.

Comment: I dont know why a button in the page load has its event handler attached and working while,,a button created in another section of the code, hasnt got its button with an eventhandler attached.. I did that test, and found that it depends on where in the code the button is created.. The page_Load seems to be triggered together with teh button event. When i press any button the logic of the button and the logic of the web application (page Load) are both launched... May be i should prevent the page Load from being executed at post back?

Comment: Whats the reason behind prepage_init..why does it work only then?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you creating the buttons?  It's probably the wrong place.  See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Try it in `PreInit` as the documentation suggests.

Comment: Problem is that the logic of creating a button depends on the logic that is in the Page Load event..so it is impossible for me to place the buttons in the prepage_init event.. and i tried to do that too..put the List into session and take it out. i followed it with debugging..still wont work

Comment: The button being created might be decided in `Page_Load` of one request, but the button should be recreated in the `PreInit` of the following request.  That is, if you're handling a postback, the control should be (re-)created in `PreInit`.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from what other posters have said.

You could try the following:

```
pgs.Click += obtainTopicsPerPage_Click;
```

And making sure the set up code is in the PreInit or PreRender events.